# Can't input values into function, because type cannot be deduced

Tags: haskell

I wanted to write a simple recursive function to help me check some values of a maths problem, however I can't seem to add any valid inputs.

Here's the function in question

```
fun 1 = 1
fun n = fun (ceiling n) + 3
```

It appears to be of type `(Integral a1, Num a, RealFrac a1) => a1 -> a`

Giving `fun` any number as input yields the following error:

```
Could not deduce (Integral a10) arising from a use of ‘fun’
    from the context (Num a)
      bound by the inferred type of it :: Num a =>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the inferred type signature, you have `Integral a1` and `RealFrac a1` as constraints, and the function overall just returns a `Num a`.  What you're saying is that this function takes a type that is both an `Integral` and `RealFrac`, already a contradiction logically but technically possible to implement in Haskell, and returns any numeric type whatsoever.  This comes from your use of `ceiling`, which has the type `(Integral b, RealFrac a) => a -> b`, which you then pass to `fun` again.  So `n` must be an `Integral`, but since you pass the result of `ceiling n` to `fun` it must also be a `RealFrac`.  The second problem is that you simply haven't given the compiler enough information to know exactly which types you're wanting to use.

My first suggestion is to give `fun` the type signature you think it should have, which I'm guessing is probably `Double -> Int`.  If you do this you'll get a type error of `No instance for (Integral Double) arising from use of ceiling ...`, meaning that you're trying to use a `Double` as an `Integral` when `Double` doesn't implement `Integral` for obvious reasons.  This tells you precisely which part of your definition is suspect.  You can choose to cast the result of `ceiling` to `Double` using `fromIntegral` or `fromInteger`.

Beyond all this, this function will never terminate unless it's called with the value `1`.  It will essentially just build up a giant thunk of adding `3` over and over again and will just eat up RAM and CPU.

Comment: well, the function is defined the way it was in the math problem, so if it never hits 1, that's why

Answer (score 1):

That's because `ceiling` returns an `Integral`, and you're recursively calling `fun` with that value, so it deduces that `fun` must accept `Integral` values, but `ceiling` takes `RealFrac` values, and you're passing to `ceiling` the argument you got from the application of `fun`, so it deduces that `fun` must also take `RealFrac` values. Hence the constraints.

In situations like this, it's best to limit the options Haskell considers during type inference by annotation your function with the type you think it should have — the error message will become more concrete/narrowed down then and will be more localized to the code under question; otherwise, type inference will analyze your entire program and consider too many options.

(also the function itself is ill-defined as the other answer points out, but that is not causing the type error, obviously)